# Drupal checkbox and radio suddenly very small

Tags: css, drupal, checkbox

I am working on a drupal website. Installing modules, adding CSS, when suddenly all my radio buttons, checkbox btns etc became very small.

I have removed all my css and disabled the latest installed modules, but they stay small. I tried with chrome console to find out why they are small but can't find anything.

So, I have no clue why they are small or how to find out. Can someone help me find out how to get them big again, and what is causing the problem ?

Comment: Trying pressing, Ctrl + 0

Comment: Yes i did all that, also, only the checkbox, radio button and upload button are smaal, all the rest is normal

Comment: please share the link so that we can review it.

Comment: it's a local website, it is not yet hosted